# Problem Attaching Files to Hotmail using Firefox 4.0 Browser

Tags: firefox

Since updating to Firefox 4.0, I'm having trouble with attaching files to my email account (Hotmail) I'm using Windows 2000. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Does FF4 even officially SUPPORT Windows 2000? o.O

Comment: @Shinrai - yup -- Firefox 4 System Requirements: Windows Operating Systems
•Windows 2000
•Windows XP
•Windows Server 2003
•Windows Vista
•Windows 7

Comment: What actual problem/trouble/result are you having?

Comment: Oh, yeah, I was so busy being shocked at the OS I forgot to ask that same question.  What @techie007 said - this is too vague.  What sort of trouble?

Comment: Definitely need a re-write here.  And an OS upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are known problems with Firefox 4 and Hotmail.  From what I recall a fair portion of the blame fell to Hotmail at last count.

This may be informational:

http://input.mozilla.com/en-US/site/http/hotmail.com